# Which polyhedra have an even number of faces touching each vertex?

Tags: geometry, terminology, polyhedra

> A two-coloring of the faces of a polyhedron is always possible when an even number of faces meet at each vertex.
>    http://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/colorings.html

Is there a name for this property?  The number of faces that meet at a vertex?  Or more specifically, a name for polyhedra with an even number?  I don't know the terminology to use to find a list of polyhedra that have it.  I've found octrahedron, cuboctahedron, and icosidodecahedron, but that's it.  In other words, I'm looking for all the polyhedra that can be painted with only 2 colors.

Comment: Since the condition is equivalent to the existence of a closed Eulerian path along the edges, something like *Eulerian polyhedron* might be fine. I've never heard that however, esp. since one might confuse this with something about Euler's polyhedron formula.

Answer (score 2):

You could call them two-colorable polyhedra.

Some other two-colorable polyhedra are the Csaszar polyhedron, the disdyakis dodecahedron, Escher's solid, the tetrakis hexahedron, various antiprisms, and a lot of the Johnson solids.